# Magento 2 Command line throw errors in developer mode

Tags: magento2.2.2, command-line, developer-mode

In production mode, my website is working fine. But as soon as I enable **developer mode**, I can not use command line any more.

In developer mode, if I use for example `php bin/magento cache:flush`, I'll get the following error.

```
Invalid Document
Element 'virtualType', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value '01' is not accepted by the pattern '(\\?[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]*)(\\[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]*)*'.
Line: 23

Element 'virtualType', attribute 'name': '01' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'phpClassName'.
Line: 23

Element 'virtualType', attribute 'name': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 23
```

This happens to every command I use in developer mode. 
What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with an IDE, find the string `<virtualType name="` in your app/code folder
or also by command-line `grep -R '<virtualType name="' app/code`

and then one of these declarations will likely have an empty name or invalid character.

If app/code does not give anything, you may have to do the same in vendor folder but less likely

if this is not easy because there are a lot of di.xml. You may disable one by one the installed third-party modules and flush the cache, try again..

Comment: I'll try this later and let you know the result. So you think it's some 3rd part modules that gives the problem?

Comment: either third-party. Often, for myself it is on my own code forgetting to write my di.xml correctly or my IDE cutting the name of the virtualType by bad copy/paste

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was the case. I had a extension that had <virtualType name="'01'">, I changed that and everything's working again.